# SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.client_address is not consistent with keepalive client connection

Tags: python, keep-alive, simplehttpserver

Here is a part of pretty standard HTTP server:

```python
class ConnectionHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "client_address=", self.client_address
        data = "Some Text"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(data))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(data)

class MyHttpServer(object):
    def __init__(self, Port=9999, ConnHandler=ConnectionHandler):
        self.Port = Port
        self.ConnHandler = ConnHandler
        self.Server = SocketServer.TCPServer(
            ('127.0.0.1', self.Port), self.ConnHandler)
        self.Server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoServer = MyHttpServer()
```

Here is client.py. It uses urllib3 for keepalive sessions:

```
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool
pool = HTTPConnectionPool('127.0.0.1:9999', maxsize=1)
pool.request('GET', '/connect')
pool.request('GET', '/ping')
pool.request('GET', '/test')
print "pool.num_connections={} pool.num_requests={}".format(
    pool.num_connections, pool.num_requests)
```

When I run client, it shows pool.num_connections=1 pool.num_requests=3, just as expected. But when I run server, here is what it shows:

```
client_address= ('127.0.0.1', 34858)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2014 01:42:45] "GET /connect HTTP/1.1" 200 -
client_address= ('127.0.0.1', 34859)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2014 01:42:45] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 -
client_address= ('127.0.0.1', 34860)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2014 01:42:45] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Shouldn't I have the same client_address port number at each request? Either I don't understand the concept of keepalive connection, or I'm doing something wrong.